# Check transactions on hardhat localnet

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, hardhat

So I want to check my local transactions running on hardhat localnet after they have done executing. Like using the transaction hash and checking the transaction details later.
Is there a good way to do it? Or is this possible?

Do I need to use ganache for this? Or is the hardhat local node from `hardhat node` enough?

EDIT: Could see the transactions in the metamask wallet itself. So that was a dumb question. Thanks.

Comment: You can also save the transaction `tx` and read the receipt like `const receipt = tx.wait()`

Comment: Oh thanks. This is cool.

Comment: @JulissaDC Is there a way to see a tx history/details through `hardhat console` ?

Answer (score 1):

you can do whatever analysis you want by checking the reciept:

```
const tx = await ....;
const txRexiept = await tx.wait(1);
console.log("the transaction details are");
console.log(txReciept);
```